# discord.py set bot activity to custom activity

Tags: python, discord.py

How do I set a discord bot's activity to custom text, I know how to set it "playing", "watching", "streaming" and "lessening to". However, I want it's activity to not start these words

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bot's can't currently have a custom status, as Rapptz explained it [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/2400#issuecomment-546757644).
Setting the bot's status to a [`discord.CustomActivity`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=custom#discord.CustomActivity) won't  create any error, but you just won't see it.

It is not recommended to make API calls in `on_ready` events, you can set your bot's activity when you define you `bot` (or `client`):

```py
from discord.ext import commands
bot = commands.Bot(activity=your_activity)

# Or

import discord
client = discord.Client(activity=your_activity)
```

Here the list of supported activities:

- [`discord.Game`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=baseactivity#discord.Game) → playing ...
- [`discord.Streaming`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=baseactivity#discord.Streaming) → streaming ...
- [`discord.Activity`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=activity#discord.Activity) → depends on [`discord.Activity.type`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=activity#discord.ActivityType)

PS: you can create game and streaming acitvities from `discord.Activity` but:

> For memory optimisation purposes, some activities are offered in
> slimmed down versions:
>
> - Game
> - Streaming